# Discord.js | random-puppy embed doesn't work

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've tried adding a command in my discord bot that shows a random image from the "frogs" subreddit, but it doesn't show the image, and if I try console.log, it sends the actual (working) link.
Here's that code:

```
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
    randomPuppy('frogs').then(url => {
        const frogEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor('froggo - r/frogs', 'https://i.imgur.com/0RLKc78.jpg?1')
            .setColor(0x348a58)
            .setThumbnail(url + '.png')
            .setFooter('aaaaaaaaaaaaa')
        setTimeout(() => { message.channel.send(frogEmbed) }, 10000);
        console.log(url)
    });
```

The result is an embed **without an image.**

**UPDATE**

I found out that most of the time it works, even with different extensions, but it has periods when it just never works for like 5 minutes. I don't know how to resolve this, and I hope it's just a Reddit or igmur api error (or just a pc error).

Happened again. This time I logged the URLs, and in that short period of time (like 3 minutes), there were no URLs in the console at all. Other commands worked, so i dont think its a connectivity problem.

Comment: I tried out this function 100 times and it always gave back a link with a file ext, 97 times .jpg and 3 times png, the issue is that you are appending `.png`, so it's an invalid link, change to `setThumbnail(url)` and it should work. If not log what url is.

Comment: @Karizma i read that discord api could only send it if it’s a png, and i found out that you can add as many extensions as you want on an igmur link that it will still works, so i thought adding it would work...

Comment: @Karizma its still not working :(

Comment: Like I said, if it didn't work log what url is. I have tried it out and `jpg` works fine for images.

Comment: @Karizma i’m not sure because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn’t, idk if it’s because of the file extensions, i’ll try logging every url

Comment: Once you do update the post with the results

Comment: @Karizma uppdated it now

Comment: Update it with the results, like when it fails

Comment: @Karizma ok, when it stops working again ill log the urls

Comment: @Karizma updated again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215702/discussion-between-karizma-and-froggit).